# get property count with entity using nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

can I am hoping someone can point me to the right direction on how to get count of a property and the entity using a single trip to sql.

```
 public class Category
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public virtual int ArticlesCount { get; set; }

        public Category()
        {
            Articles=new List<Article>();

        }



        public virtual void AddArticle(Article article)
        {
            article.Category = this;
            Articles.Add(article);
        }
        public virtual void RemoveArticle(Article article)
        {
            Articles.Remove(article);
        }

    }

     public class CategoryMap:ClassMap<Category>
        {
            public CategoryMap()
            {

                Table("Categories");
                Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
                Map(x => x.Description);
               HasMany(x => x.Articles).KeyColumn("CategoryId").Fetch.Join();
                Cache.ReadWrite();
            }

        }
```

My goal is to get the all Categories and the count of the associated articles if there is any.
I have tried this

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category));
 crit.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()                     
 .Add(Projections.Property("Description"), "Description")
 .Add(Projections.Count("Articles"), "ArticlesCount"));
 crit.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean (typeof(Category)));
                    var aa=crit.List();
```

unfortunately the generated sql shows the count of the Category table not the Articles list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi-query, multiple sql statements but it is one trip to the database.

Here is an example from the nhibernate documentation:
https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/performance.html

```
IMultiQuery multiQuery = s.CreateMultiQuery()
    .Add(s.CreateQuery("from Item i where i.Id > ?")
            .SetInt32(0, 50).SetFirstResult(10))
    .Add(s.CreateQuery("select count(*) from Item i where i.Id > ?")
            .SetInt32(0, 50));
IList results = multiQuery.List();
IList items = (IList)results[0];
long count = (long)((IList)results[1])[0];
```

Maybe not exactly what you were thinking.